# How can I reduce the bottom margin of a panel with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my Bootstrap 3.0.3 customization:

```
@font-size-base 12px
@grid-gutter-width 10px

@navbar-margin-bottom 10px

@line-height-base 1.67

@padding-large-vertical @padding-base-vertical
@padding-large-horizontal @padding-base-horizontal
@border-radius-large @border-radius-base
```

Most of the things are OK, except for the bottom margin of the panel.

Red box shows the bottom margin of the panel and ivory color shows the item value.

I want to reduce the bottom margin of the panel to 5px.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Chrome Dev Tools:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: So use Chrome devtools...?  Right click that empty space, find out what fits there and go alter it.  Am I missing something bigger here?

Comment: @Dreyck // great. I changed my question. it was bottom margin of panel only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to custermize with getbootstrap.com.
I changed it in style sheet like this.

```
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `style={{"margin-bottom":"5px"}}` inside the component tag.

Example:

```html
<Panel header={title} eventKey={title} collapsible bsStyle="info" style={{"margin-bottom":"5px"}}>
```